# Remove item from generic list based on date condition

Tags: c#, vb.net, list

How to remove an item from the list based on condition.

Keep all the items in the list but if doc id is 1 then keep the one with latest (max) date.

List contains items with ID's and dates. List can have multiple items with same ids except id 1.

Lets say list has 3 items one of them has id 2 and the rest has id 1 then the item with id 1 with latest date needs to be in the list and rest will be removed from the list.

After removing item list will have two items with id 1 and 2.

I have tried this but no luck.

```
var newest = thelist.MaxBy(x => x.DateTimeField);
```

Eaxmple:

if there are 4 elements (id: 1, Date: Now), (id: 2, Date: Now), (id: 1, Date: Yesterday), (id: 2, Date: Yesterday) results will be
(id: 1, Date: Now), (id: 2, Date: Now),(id: 2, Date: Yesterday)

Comment: may be i need to add condition where x.DoctypeID = 1?

Comment: Why did you add two tags `C#` and `vb.net` ?

Comment: first you say `List can have multiple items with same ids except id 1` then `Lets say list has 3 items one of them has id 2 and the rest has id 1` is 1 unique or not?

Comment: It will give opportunity to both c# and vb.net experts to answer this question as i use both languages.

Comment: @Plutonix; 1 is unique as they can't have same dates.

Comment: [List<T>.RemoveAll (Predicate<T>)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You want to remove from every duplicate id the old results or just from Id=1 specifically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you properly then try to use something like that:

```
var maxDateValue = thelist.Where(x => x.DoctypeID == 1).Max(c => c.DateTimeField);
thelist.RemoveAll(x => x.DoctypeID == 1 & x.DateTimeField != maxDateValue);
```

**UPDATE**

```
var idValue = 1; //to prevent the use of magic numbers
IList<yourType> filteredList = new List(thelist.Where(x => x.DoctypeID == idValue ));
var maxDateValue = filteredList.Max(c => c.DateTimeField);
thelist.RemoveAll(filteredList.Where(x.DateTimeField != maxDateValue));
```

Comment: thanks for your the answer, just quick question on max function. Can i use it for integer field?

Comment: yes, of cource. I'll try to improve the code in a few minutes because it is not very nice :)

Comment: @user1263981 I've made some refactoring of code. Please see

Answer (score 1):

The following will remove on every duplicate Id the oldest items.

```
var res = thelist
            .GroupBy(p => p.Id)
            .SelectMany(grp => grp.Where(pp => grp.Max(item => item.DateTimeField) == pp.DateTimeField));
```

You can also use:

```
var res = thelist
            .GroupBy(r => r.Id)
            .SelectMany(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(p => p.DateTimeField).Take(1));
```

Comment: I want to keep all the items in the list but if doc id is 1 then keep the one with latest (max) date.

Answer (score 0):

Find the max date and then remove else

```
    var maxDate = thelist.Where(x => x.id == 1).Max(x => x.Date);
    thelist.RemoveAll(x => x.id == 1 && x.Date != maxDate);
```

Comment: I want (id: 1, Date: Now), (id: 2, Date: Now) and (id: 2, Date: Yesterday)

Comment: condition suppose to apply on items with doc id = 1

Comment: @user1263981 Updated back to remove all function